# About time complexity of the code snippet

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve a question on [Pramp](https://www.Pramp.com):

> Implement a function reverseWords that reverses the order of the words in the array in the most efficient manner.
>
> Ex: arr = [ 'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', '  ',
>                   'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', '  ',
>                   'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e' ]
>
> output: [ 'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', '  ',
>             'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', '  ',
>             'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't' ]

The Python-like pseudo-code which they have given is as follows:

```
function reverseWords(arr):
    # reverse all characters:
    n = arr.length
    mirrorReverse(arr, 0, n-1)

    # reverse each word:
    wordStart = null
    for i from 0 to n-1:
        if (arr[i] == ' '):
            if (wordStart != null):
                mirrorReverse(arr, wordStart, i-1)
                wordStart = null
        else if (i == n-1):
            if (wordStart != null):
                mirrorReverse(arr, wordStart, i)
        else:
            if (wordStart == null):
                wordStart = i

    return arr


# helper function - reverses the order of items in arr
# please note that this is language dependent:
# if are arrays sent by value, reversing should be done in place

function mirrorReverse(arr, start, end):
    tmp = null
    while (start < end):
        tmp = arr[start]
        arr[start] = arr[end]
        arr[end] = tmp
        start++
        end--
```

They say that the time complexity is **O(n)**, essentially because they are *traversing the array twice with a constant number of actions for each item*.  Co-incidentally, I came up with the exact same approach using `stringstreams` in C++, but thought that it was not efficient!

I think the time complexity of this snippet should be **O(mn)**, where `m` is the number of words in the string and `n` is the average number of alphabets in each word.  This is so because we iterate over all the elements in the input and in the worst case, `mirrorReverse()` visits all the elements again for reversing, for a given `i`.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **O(n)**, `n` refers to the length of the input (total characters), not the quantity of words.  I suspect you're confused because the code uses a variable `n` in the latter sense.

Note the explanation: "traversing the array ...".  "The array" consists of individual characters.

The implementation seems a bit silly to me; it's much more readable to:

1. Join letter groups into words.
2. Reverse the word order (including spaces) with a trivial list slice.
3. Expand the words back into characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So, do you mean to say that both of us are correct (with respect to our own definitions)?

Comment: Yes; they used appropriate terminology for such discussions.  You understand the underlying situation quite well.  Personally, I'd have a quick chat with their tech writer ...

Comment: Haha.  Got your point.  Thank you! :)  I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.